# Wide character in subroutine entry in otrs on Postgres 9.4beta1

Tags: perl, otrs, postgresql-9.4

After upgrading from Postgres 9.1.2 to Postgres 9.4beta1, OTRS 3.3.5 stopped working with a Perl error found in http-error.log, raised when closing a ticket. The error is:

> Wide character in subroutine entry at [...]/Kernel/System.DB.pm line 499

The line 499 is the following:

```
if ( !$Self->{dbh}->do( $Param{SQL}, undef, @Array ) ) {
```

It seems that the Perl script fails while executing a query.

My Perl version is v5.16.3.

I searched a lot but no solution worked for me so far.

Comment: What does your input SQL look like?

Comment: Sorry. Not a Perl expert. I do I print the statement?

Comment: I have the same problem. I upgraded from Debian 7 to 8. OTRS 3.3.9 worked with Postres 9.1 but after the upgrade to Postgres 9.4 I get this error. Can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning not an error. Looking in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) gives us the explanation.

> **Wide character in %s**
>
> (S utf8) Perl met a wide character (>255) when it wasn't expecting
>   one. This warning is by default on for I/O (like print). The easiest
>   way to quiet this warning is simply to add the :utf8 layer to the
>   output, e.g. binmode STDOUT, ':utf8' . Another way to turn off the
>   warning is to add no warnings 'utf8'; but that is often closer to
>   cheating. In general, you are supposed to explicitly mark the
>   filehandle with an encoding, see open and binmode.

You have utf8-encoded characters where Perl is expecting to see bytes. You probably need to `encode()` your data before it gets to this point.

Comment: Actually the script stops and the web server gives an error page (in the errorlog I see "the script terminated unexpectedly").